# How to know the available time and date in Reservation/CheckIn Program

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using Visual Basic.Net and I have a problem in knowing the available Date, Time, and Room for the reservation/checkin of Hotel/Resort Reservation Program. Here in this code provided below, when I tried to reserve the specific room in a specific date and time, then restart the program, when I tried to save again with the unavailable room/date/time, the program's condition has wrongly allowed to save it again with the conflict schedule. I am using visual basic. Thank you :)

[image: Program Output]

[image: Database using MSAccess]

Dim varConflictSched As Boolean = False

```
        Dim dsCheckIn As New DataSet
        Dim daCheckIn As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblCheckIn ORDER BY ID", MyConn)
        daCheckIn.Fill(dsCheckIn, "tblCheckIn")

        Dim DateTimeRangeNewIn(Val(Me.txtstaying.Text)) As DateTime
        Dim DateCheckInNew As DateTime = Me.dtpCheckIn.Value

        For a As Integer = 0 To dsCheckIn.Tables("tblCheckIn").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim DateTimeRangeOldIn(dsCheckIn.Tables("tblCheckIn").Rows(a)("Staying")) As DateTime

            REM Check if the room number is in used
            If Me.cbRoomNumber.SelectedItem = dsCheckIn.Tables("tblCheckIn").Rows(a)("RoomNumber").ToString Then

                REM Check if the date and time of the specified room number is in used
                Dim varCheckInDate As DateTime = dsCheckIn.Tables("tblCheckIn").Rows(a)("CheckInDate")

                For b As Integer = 0 To dsCheckIn.Tables("tblCheckIn").Rows(a)("Staying")
                    For c As Integer = 0 To Val(Me.txtstaying.Text)
                        DateTimeRangeOldIn(b) = varCheckInDate.AddDays(b)
                        DateTimeRangeNewIn(c) = DateCheckInNew.AddDays(c)

                        If DateTimeRangeOldIn(b).Date = DateTimeRangeNewIn(c).Date Then
                            If DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, DateTimeRangeOldIn(b), DateTimeRangeNewIn(c)) <= 0 Then
                                varConflictSched = True
                                Exit For

                            End If

                        End If

                    Next

                Next

            End If

        Next

        If Me.txtAmount.Text = "" Or Me.txtSearch.Text = "" Or Me.txtstaying.Text = "" Or Me.txtTotal.Text = "" Or Me.cbRoomNumber.SelectedIndex = -1 Or Me.cbRoomtype.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Required field(s) should not be left blank" & vbCrLf & "Please try again", "NO BLANK SPACE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        ElseIf varConflictSched = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Can't set schedule with this date." & vbCrLf & "Please insert another date.", "CONFLICT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Else
            Dim DAdapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblCheckIN ORDER BY ID ", MyConn)
            Dim DSet As New DataSet
            DAdapter.Fill(DSet, "tblCheckIN")
            Dim NewID As Integer = DSet.Tables("tblCheckIN").Rows(DSet.Tables("tblCheckIN").Rows.Count - 1)("ID") + 1

            Dim CommCheckIn As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO tblCheckIN (ID,CustomerID,Roomtype,RoomNumber,Amount,CheckInDate,Staying)VALUES(" & NewID & ",'" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "','" & Me.cbRoomtype.SelectedItem & "','" & Me.cbRoomNumber.SelectedItem & "','" & Me.txtAmount.Text & "','" & Me.dtpCheckIn.Value & "' , '" & Me.txtstaying.Text & "')", MyConn)

            MyConn.Open()
            CommCheckIn.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MyConn.Close()

            MessageBox.Show("Your Checking-In is succesfully saved. ", "SAVED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            Me.ClearAll()

        End If
```

Comment: In my code below, using my recorded check-in date/time/room in the database, my program will check whether in the range of new entered date/time/room will have any conflict in the range of date/time/room from my database. I have used the array to store the range :)

Comment: Restarting the program probably has nothing to do with this. This has to do with 2 things: your Database Schema, and a fault in your business logic. Two separate parties shouldn't be allowed to book the same room, during the same time frame. You shouldn't even display a booked room during the time period someone is searching for - this will mitigate these scenarios

Comment: I was wondering if the that was the way of getting time interval between two dates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need looping code to find a collision.

A collision occurs when:

```
RequestionStartDate <= EndDate
   And 
RequestEndDate >= StartDate
```

Of course you have to add roomnumber to above, but it rather simple.

So on book button, your code will do this:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rstData As New DataSet
Dim daRead As SqlDataAdapter
strSQL = "select * from tblCheckIn where RoomNumber = @RoomNum " & _
         " AND ( (@CheckIn <= CheckOutDate) AND (@CheckOut >= CheckInDate) )"
Dim MySql As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, GetCon)
MySql.Parameters.Add("@RoomNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.RoomNumber.Value
MySql.Parameters.Add("@CheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.dtpCheckIn.Value
MySql.Parameters.Add("@CheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.dtpCheckOut.Value

daRead.SelectCommand = MySql
daRead.Fill(rstData)
If rstData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox("you have a booking collsion")
End If
```

The above works since you never allow a collsion, and the above will return any record that you "over lap". this includes the cases like this:

```
RequestStart                   RequestEnd
  |                              |
       | exsiting Start/end |
```

or

```
    RequestStart                   RequestEnd
      |                              |
  | exist Start                         Exist end |
```

or

```
RequestStart               RequestEnd
    |                           |
          | exist Start                    Exist end |
```

in fact any combination of ANY overlap will be found by the above simple query.

Comment: Owh! I was taken aback by the simplicity of the code you've provided. It's easy to comprehend, I was so crazy doing such labyrinthine way lol :-D